# Incomplete image retrieved using google scripts - possible timeout issue

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch

Using Google Scripts to retrieve images from a URL, with the given MIME type, and save them to a google drive.

When I export the images from the Google Drive to disk, only part of the image is displayed.
My logs show that my script runs, and can take as much as a minute to run the retrieve.

Manual download (by entering the URL in a browser), can take up to 2 or 3 mins to download the image, which could be up to 50MB.   But this is a complete image and displayed in full.

Is my script timing out?
How can I extend or ensure the method remains active until the completion of the retrieval?

Sample code:

```
            //image type provided by source, with URL
            var imageType = "image/png"
            var url =  ***insert url here ***

            var headers = {
                "Accept": imageType,
                "Content-Type": imageType,
                "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password)
            };

            //method to download file
            var options = {
                "method": "get",
                "headers": headers
            };

            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch( ***ImageUrl*** , options);
            var responseBlob = response.getBlob();

            //target folder
            var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById( ***folderId*** );

            //create file in folder, as specified type
            var file = folder.createFile(responseBlob.getAs(imageType));
```

---

### Update:

Helpful suggestion followed, by using the Range header. 
Headers code now looks like this:

```
                var headers = {
                "Accept": imageType,
                "Content-Type": imageType,
                "Range": bytes=0-500,
                "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password)
            };
```

I was expecting a response code of 206, but still get a response code of 200.

Response headers:

```
    headers({
    'Cache-Control': "private",
    Server: "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    'x-aspnet-version': "4.0.30319",
    'Set-Cookie': "NSC_wfoeps01=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdbb41d7b58dfc80780e53c974e9617a1f471e88fcxxxxxxxxxxx;path=/;secure;httponly",
    'Content-Length': "59070463",
    Date: "Fri, 30 Nov 2018 14:16:46 GMT",
    'Content-Type': "image/png"
})
```

---

### Update:

The server from which I am trying to download from does not support Partial downloads (at present).
This solution of usingt RANGE would have worked if the server did support Partial downloads.

Thank you for the help.   Much appreciated.

Comment: I think that in my experience, the timeout of UrlFetchApp might have been about 1 minute. By this, in your case, the downloaded image might become incomplete image. So as a workaround, how about using [Partial download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#partial_download)? This can achieve the resumable download.

Comment: Forgot to add... my code successfully retrieves smaller images, but is struggling with the large images

My fetch is inside a try/ catch block too

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for the tip
I'll investigate this now :)

Comment: By the way, the maximum size which can be downloaded by one call of UrlFetchApp is 50 MB. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations Also please be careful this.

Comment: @Tanaike, please forgive me for asking, ...   Does this apply to only retrieval of images from Google Drive?  if I'm retrieving the image from a non googleDrive server, i.e. image provided by a 3rd party, is there something I can do?

Comment: When the partial data can be downloaded using ``range`` for the server, this method can be used. I think that most site can be downloaded using ``range``. But I'm not sure whether the site you are using can be used ``range``. When you tried this, what result did you get?

Comment: @Tanaike, I got a code 200 response, and was expecting a code 216.   I'm guessing the server that I'm sending the request to, doesn't support Partial download.   I'm kind of learning this all :)

Comment: I'm really sorry my comments were not useful for your situation. If you want, I would like to delete my comments.

Comment: @Tanaike, your suggestions were perfect and most helpful.   I can confirm that at present, the server that I am calling does not support Partial downloads.

Please feel free to clean up the comments by deleting.  

I really appreciate your help and I have learned a lot  :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I'm sorry your issue was not resolved.